# how to extract 2 characters from a string

Tags: vb.net, vb6

am in a confusion of extracting sub string  fro a given string according to the following algorithm,

**Algorithm**

every input string is of the format: 3nm , 4gn , 77jk so on..(ie., a string followed by a number)
now what i need is that extract the alphabet from the string..

**example**

input: 77nm
output : nm

my contribution:

```
Private Function getbyte(s As String, ByVal place As Integer) As String
   If place < Len(s) Then
      place = place + 1
      getbyte = Mid(s, place, 1)
   Else
      getbyte = ""
   End If
End Function
```

but it will not solve my problem as it returns number as well as digits

Comment: I'm guessing a RegEx expert can solve that pretty easily.
(Did you mean (ie., a number followed by a string) ??)

Comment: you want to eliminate all numeric? and you using [tag:vb6] or [tag:vb.net], it's different

Comment: like this: '77nm' 77 is a number and 'nm' is a astring

Comment: i need the alphabet for further process, i am using vb as well as vb.net

Comment: what is the value of the argument "place" ? how do you calculate it ?

Comment: place is an integer, if the string is '77nm' and place is '0' means the function will return '7'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) to extract only letters:

```
Dim input As String = "3nm , 4gn , 77jk"
Dim output As String = New String((From c As Char In input Select c Where Char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray())
```

*Result:*

> nmgnjk

You can also encapsulate the LINQ into an extension method.

```
<Extension()>
Public Module Extensions

    <Extension()>
    Public Function Extract(input As String, predicate As Predicate(Of Char)) As String
        Return New String((From c As Char In input Select c Where predicate.Invoke(c)).ToArray())
    End Function

End Module
```

*Usage*

```
output = input.Extract(Function(c As Char) Char.IsLetter(c))
```